# Change value of variable if/when browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, I'm a complete beginner.

I've got 3 divs (div1, div2, and div3).

div1, div2, and div3 appear in the source code in that order.

div1 has a fixed height, div2's height is set to fill the rest of the visible viewport space. Then, when you scroll down, you get to div3.

I'm wanting to give div3 negative top-margin that is equal to the height of div2.

I'm able to get as far as calculating the height of div2 when the page loads and apply div2's height as negative top-margin to div3, but I would like to RE-calculate div2's height if/when the browser is resized, and then RE-apply it as negative top-margin to div3.

Here's how far I got:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var headerHeight;
var topHeight;
var correctHeight;

function setWidth() {
headerHeight= $("#header-space").height();
    topHeight = $( window ).height(); 
correctHeight = topHeight - headerHeight;

};

setWidth();

$(window).resize(setWidth);

$(".anchorsnav").css("margin-top", '-' + correctHeight + 'px');

});
```

I know that there are most likely far better ways of achieving the effect that I'm trying for here, but for layman's sake, let's assume that the markup (div1..div2..div3)is what I have got to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Put the call to `.css()` in `setWidth()`, so it will be done when you resize.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var headerHeight;
  var topHeight;
  var correctHeight;

  function setWidth() {
    headerHeight = $("#header-space").height();
    topHeight = $(window).height();
    correctHeight = topHeight - headerHeight;
    $(".anchorsnav").css("margin-top", '-' + correctHeight + 'px');
  };

  setWidth();
  $(window).resize(setWidth);
});
```

You might also want to add [debouncing](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) to your resize handler, so it doesn't run until the user is finished resizing.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't mega far off then :)

But alas, it's still not working...Although, there seems to ba flicker now as i resize the browser with the element appearing for brief instances in the place that I want it to be...so it's almost there.

As I mentioned, I'm a complete beginner, so I don't have the foggiest idea how to approach adding the debouncing. I'll keep looking into it though. 

Many thanks

Comment: Did you follow the link I provided for debouncing?

Comment: I did, but even after reading through it diligently, I wouldn't know where to put what and what to change to what.

Comment: You'll probably need to find a real programmer to help you. SO is not the way to solve this.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would be the case. Thanks again for your help. Cheers